# I am having trouble linking Css File to Django Template

Tags: css, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I just started learning django framework and i tried to add and use static files to design a template(to change the background) of webpage with simple css but my css file doesn't seem to link with html template as the background did not change.

I looked up various solutions and it doesn't seem i am doing anything wrong in the code but it still doesn't work. Please look at the code, what could i be missing?

Here is the code for the template;

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="music/style.css">


{% if all_albums %}
<h3>My Albums</h3>
<ul>
    {% for album in all_albums %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}">{{album.album_title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}
<h3>You don't have any albums</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Here is the css;

```
body{
    background: white url("images/blackbackground.jpg");
}
```

I expected the background to change but it didn't. The server returned error message "Not Found: /music/music/style.css
[01/Feb/2019 12:15:26] "GET /music/music/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2559" guys what am i missing?

Comment: why is it /music/music ? seems confusing, have you tried just `href="./style.css"`

Answer (score 1):

To make the static files work on Django you need to have a couple of variables in place.

First, in your `settings.py` you'll have to have your static file variables set.

Here I show you an example of the one I use:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'static',
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

This means that you will need to have a static folder in the same folder as your main app.

For example:

```sh
├── apps
│   ├── api
│   ├── blog
│   └── home
├── manage.py
├── media
│   ├── images
│   └── original_images
├── requirements
│   ├── base.txt
│   ├── development.txt
│   └── production.txt
├── src    -----> THIS IS MY MAIN FOLDER
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── locale
│   ├── media
│   ├── settings ------> THIS IS MY SETTINGS FOLDER
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── static    ------> THIS IS MY STATIC FOLDER
│   ├── css
│   ├── figures
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── img
├── templates
│   └── base.html
└── utilities
```

Next, you'll need to add this to your main `urls.py`:

```py
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

# Serve static files with Django. Normally this is for development purposes.
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

After that, the last part goes into your templates, you'll need to load static template tags and use the following syntax:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'music/style.css' %}">
```

At the end, it will render something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/music/style.css">
```